# Avoiding store reinitialization with unstated

Tags: reactjs, state-management, unstated

I am trying out `unstated` (https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated) and like its simplicity but am experiencing unexpected behavior.  At the top level I have:

```
<Provider>
  <Subscribe to={[MyDataContainer]}>
    {myDataStore => (
      <TopLevelComponent dataStore={myDataStore} />
    )}
  </Subscribe>
</Provider>
```

Then way down my component tree, I access the store again using something like this:

```
  <Subscribe to={[MyDataContainer]}>
    {myDataStore => (
      <Leaf dataStore={myDataStore} />
    )}
  </Subscribe>
```

This works great as long as my tree stays the same.  As soon as I have a state change that requires rebuilding the leaves, the state object in my data container gets re-initialized and wiped out.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve this in two different ways:

1. Expose an instance of your `Container` instead of the class.
2. Instantiate the Container and inject it in your `<Provider>`.

In the first option, the instance remains the same on every `import`, and you will have `<Subscribe to={[instance]}>`. [Unstated doc](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated#passing-your-own-instances-directly-to-subscribe-to)

In the second, you can do `<Subscribe to={[ContainerClass]}>` but Unstated will try to resolve if there is an instance of that class injected through the `<Provider>` and use that instance instead of re-instantiate. [Unstated doc](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated#provider)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by moving the `Provider` to the `App` level, above any component that receives `props`/re-renders.